# Text Editor does not change with theme

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

My visual studios seems to have just randomly broken.

The text editor does not seem to change colors at all upon the theme being changed.

for example, if the theme is dark the surrounding windows will all format to the correct color but the editor itself remains the "light" theme. It doesn't even respond to the blue theme.

I can manually edit the colors, but that seems to be all I can do right now.

Comment: Off-topic on SO since unrelated to any source code that you can show in your question. You could switch to some other [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor)

Comment: I like Visual Studio in terms of features and what I can come to expect of it, I'm just having issues with theme being broken. It's not like there haven't been questions on SO about theme issues with VS.

Comment: https://superuser.com/ could be a better place to ask

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem where no matter which theme I selected the text editor would be light as you say.

I resolved this by going to Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors and with Text Editor selected in the top drop down I clicked Use Defaults and that switched it back to being of the theme which you selected in General.